A 90s film with where the hero falls off a building and doesn't get hurt
I'm looking for a movie I saw in the 90s, maybe early 2000s. From what I remember the atmosphere of the film it's an American movvie, also, I think that the main character is played by Tim Robbins. From my recollection, the movie is either a drama or a family movie, definitely not a comedy one.
In this movie, the main character jumps off the window of a tall building and his fall is lengthy. Around 1 meter from the ground, it looks like the time stops for everybody but him. Things happen and then he somehow realizes that he shouldn't have jumped and he safely lands on his feet.
Does anyone know which movie this is?

Hudsucker proxy (1994) directed by the Coen brothers: 


IMDB link
The janitor stops the clock so he doesn't fall.
Also I think this film would qualify as a comedy in my opinion as it's a homage to the fast talking films from the 30/40's.

Yes, that's the one, thanks! Also, you were fast ;-)

Regarding the comedy statement, I hadn't seen that movie completely, but this scene marked my mind and I don't remind any comic element from it.

Coen Brothers movies are often hard to qualify as comedy or drama. Hudsucker Proxy was really quirky and funny at the start got into a weird realm of the supernatural at the end.

@BrettFromLA I think this one is clearer than others such as fargo where there may have been some comedy moments, but this film is a light hearted feelgood/romantic film with many comedic devices throughout
